# How to replace decorView in Android?

Tags: android

As it knows, we can get Android top-hierarhy `Views` via `Activity.getWindow().getDecorView()` and `Activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content)`.

Is it possible to replace the standard set of custom Views?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do, but I think you can find your answer if you know more about the android view hierarchy. The following two documents may be helpful:

1, You can use the Hierarchy Viewer to analyse your view hierarchy:
http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html

2, The following blog is related to the android view hierarchy:
http://www.curious-creature.org/category/android/page/2/

Answer (score 0):

There is no way unless you have access to the framework code.